# C# WinForm .Visible and Image Change Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

I am attempting to create a WinForm menu system in C# for WinCE 6.0.

The general idea for this menu system is that there are a few picture boxes that act as buttons along the bottom of the screen. These allow for switches between general settings (screen brightness, language, etc.), date/time settings and other system specific settings. And there are a few more picture boxes that act as buttons in the middle of the screen along with labels defining the options for the user.

So, quick example. Entering the settings menu brings you to the general settings by default:

```
labelTitle.Text = "General";
labelOption1.Text = "Brightness";
picOption1Left.Image = bmpDown;
picOption1Right.Image = bmpUp;
```

Tapping on the down arrow next to brightness, will lower the screen brightness; up arrow will raise brightness.

Tapping the Date/Time option button along the bottom of the screen will change these fields to the following:

```
labelTitle.Text = "Date and Time";
labelOption1.Text = "Time";
picOption1Left.Visible = false;
picOption2Right.Image = bmpInput;
```

Only one image is used for this setting. Tapping the input image will allow the user to input the time through a virtual keyboard, or possible other means.

Thats the basic concept. The problem is that after switching images and or toggling the .Visible value between true and false eventually cause the device to stall and crash. My troubleshooting so far makes me think this is some sort of issue with memory.

Why would I be consuming memory (enough to make the device crash) just by toggling visibility or changing the image associated with an asset? Tested and both functions will cause the crash. Is there something bad about programming a menu system this way? Is there a better way to reach this goal? Should I consider programming in a different language since an embedded device will be more limited? I appreciate any thoughts and/or advice on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the `bmpInput`, `bmpUp`, and `bmpDown` variables initialized only once, or repeatedly?

Comment: Declared globally, initialized in the form's constructor. Just once.